# Incompatible glue units error using \implies and \iff in Beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode, spacing

I'm experiencing some strange behavior with Beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  $\alert<1>{\implies}$
  %% \alert<1>{$\implies$}         % Works!
  %% $\alert<1>{\Longrightarrow}$  % Works!
  %% \alert<1>{$\iff$}             % Works!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The previous code will raise an error:

> ! Incompatible glue units.
>
> \reset@color ->\beamer@lastskip =\lastskip
> \edef \beamer@lastskiptexta {\the...
>
> l.9 \end{frame}

I have the same issue with `$\alert<1>{\iff}$`. But all of the other commented options work smoothly. Which is the relevant difference between `\implies` and `\Longrightarrow` here? In any casse, the PDF output looks fine to me.

I'm running pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian), packed with Debian Testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\implies` has an explicit `\;` in its definition which adds a muskip length which is incompatible with standard skip (length) commands. You can hide that with an extra set of braces

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  $\alert<1>{{\implies}}$
  %% \alert<1>{$\implies$}         % Works!
  %% $\alert<1>{\Longrightarrow}$  % Works!
  %% \alert<1>{$\iff$}             % Works!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```