# `Incompatible glue units` error when modifying the `muskip` around an align environment

Tags: math-mode, align, setlength

I have a long equation which I am trying to fit into a single line:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside]{article}

%%% DOCUMENT SETUP %%%
\PassOptionsToPackage{medium}{titlesec}

% packages and configurations come here (see list below).
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\title{My title}
\author{Myself}

\date{\today{}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\newcommand{\indicator}[1]{\mathbbm{1}_{\{#1\}}}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\mathrm{sgn}}

\begin{align}
    \Lambda=
    \frac{1}{x}\left(
        \indicator{z\geq0}
        -e^{-xt}\Phi\left(\beta_0\right)
        +\frac{e^{-zy}}{2}\left(
            e^{-zp}\left(\frac{y}{p}-1\right)\Phi\left(\sgn(z)\beta_1\right)
            -e^{zp}\left(\frac{y}{p}+1\right)\Phi\left(-\sgn(z)\beta_2\right)
        \right)
    \right)
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41917/104780), I have tried to compact the equation by modifying the values of `\thinmuskip` and `\medmuskip`:

```latex
\begingroup
\setlength{\thinmuskip}{0mu}
\setlength{\medmuskip}{0mu}
\begin{align}
    \Lambda=
    \frac{1}{x}\left(
        \indicator{z\geq0}
        -e^{-xt}\Phi\left(\beta_0\right)
        +\frac{e^{-zy}}{2}\left(
            e^{-zp}\left(\frac{y}{p}-1\right)\Phi\left(\sgn(z)\beta_1\right)
            -e^{zp}\left(\frac{y}{p}+1\right)\Phi\left(-\sgn(z)\beta_2\right)
        \right)
    \right)
\end{align}
\endgroup
```

However I am getting the following errors:

```latex
! Incompatible glue units.               \setlength{\thinmuskip}{0mu}
! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). \setlength{\medmuskip}{0mu}
```

Moreover, the string `u!` appears in my output at the place where the group begins.

There are other questions on this site about this sort of error, such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/617891/104780), but it seems unrelated to the problem at hand.

**What is causing my code to fail here?**

*Edit*: packages/settings for my document

```latex
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[textsize=footnotesize,tickmarkheight=3pt]{todonotes}
\usepackage{setspace}

% MATHS %
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{pifont}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\bibliographystyle{myauthordate3}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,round,semicolon,}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\titleformat{\subparagraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subparagraph}{\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{.75ex plus .1ex}

\makeatletter
\def\today{%
    \two@digits{\the\day}-%
    \ifcase\month\or%
    Jan\or Feb\or Mar\or Apr\or May\or Jun\or%
    Jul\or Aug\or Sep\or Oct\or Nov\or Dec\fi-%
    \number\year%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\indicator}[1]{\mathbbm{1}_{\{#1\}}}
\newcommand{\sgn}{\mathrm{sgn}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vast}{\bBigg@{4}}
\newcommand{\Vast}{\bBigg@{5}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: You shouldn't set `\thinmuskip` and `\medmuskip` with `\setlength` if you load the `calc` package. Do you see why we always ask for minimal examples?

Comment: @egreg I am not loading `calc`, at least directly. I will add some of the (math-related) packages I load.

Comment: As I said, a minimal example showing the issue is needed.

Comment: The edit is ***not*** a minimal example. Anyway, my answer covers the business. Note that it should be `\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}` not with `\newcommand`.

Comment: I suggest splitting this into two lines, using `multline` instead of `align` and breaking just before the plus sign.  You'll have to size the first parenthesis, using `\biggl(` and indicate the break as `\\ \left. to match the final parenthesis.  Yes, a more complete example would have been helpful.

Comment: @barbarabeeton what is missing from the example?

Comment: The example was not complete when I started experimenting.  It lacked at least a document class.  It has been completed since.

Comment: @barbarabeeton okay thank you. I wasn't aware of `multline` and the left/right alignment behavior.

Comment: Not related to the problem, but don't load packages unless you actually _need_ them, and don't load the same package more than once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scalerel` package loads `calc`. Once the latter package is called, it's not possible to set muskips with `\setlength`.

Just do

```
\thinmuskip=0mu
\medmuskip=0mu
```

instead of `\setlength`.

Comment: This solution worked.

Comment: And it's really weird that a working solution gets a downvote…

Comment: The working solution gets my acceptance; the rudeness (which you have now removed), the downvote.

Comment: OK, downvoted your question for not presenting a minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

There's been a lot of thought put into the default spacing.  Instead of changing that, I would split the equation into two:

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\newcommand{\indicator}[1]{\mathbbm{1}_{\{#1\}}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{sgn}
\begin{document}
\begin{multline}
    \Lambda=
    \frac{1}{x}\biggl(
        \indicator{z\geq0}
        -e^{-xt}\Phi(\beta_0)\\
        +\frac{e^{-zy}}{2}\Bigl(
            e^{-zp}\Bigl(\frac{y}{p}-1\Bigr)\Phi(\sgn(z)\beta_1)
            -e^{zp}\Bigl(\frac{y}{p}+1\Bigr)\Phi(-\sgn(z)\beta_2)
        \Bigr)
    \biggr)
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

This renders as:
[image: code output]

I've also changed out the `\left` and `\right`, since they aren't quite optimal in this case (I can't find the appropriate Q&A at the moment).

A postscript on minimal examples: we only need `amsmath` and `bbm` in order to compile the example.  We only need the document class options and `geometry` to determine the size of the avaiable text area.  Everything else makes your example (1) more difficult to follow and (2) not compilable as a single block of code.

Comment: I think you accidentally mis-matched the sizes of your parentheses pairs.

Comment: Please take a closer look at the parentheses -- the first (on the first line) and the last (at the end) don't match in size, and they should.  (That's the benefit of `\left ... \right`, but that, of course, doesn't work on split lines.)

Comment: @mickep Oops.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oops.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @Teepeemm I was displaying the rest of packages in case one of them loaded the `calc` package.

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw But it would have been possible to comment out the various packages that you load to see if you still have the error.  That would have narrowed things down to scalerel, even if you don't know why scalerel caused the problem.  You also never placed your code into one block that we can copy and paste: in order to get the error you reported, I would need the first 4 lines of your first code block, then your third code block, some more of your first code block, your second code block, and then the end of your first code block.